# How to use while loops to repeat a programme

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently completing a programme that generates a population model.
The programme needs to repeat itself, so when done doing one option, it must return to the menu.

I have tried various solutions to tackle this problem, such as creating a function for the menu (however functions restrict you from making global variables)

I have also tried creating a while loop which looks something like this:

```
import csv
import time
time.sleep(1)
menu = True
while menu:
    print ("1. Set the Generation 0 values")
    print ("2. Display the Generation 0 values")
    print ("3. Run the model")
    print ("4. Export data")
    print ("5. Exit")
```

but it come up as this:

```
1. Set the Generation 0 values
2. Display the Generation 0 values
3. Run the model
4. Export data
5. Exit
1. Set the Generation 0 values
2. Display the Generation 0 values
3. Run the model
4. Export data
5. Exit
```

It comes up like this repeatably!

So the main question is how can I repeat the menu, I know that using the while loop helps, but how do I stop it from repeating?

Answer (score 0):

You need something in the loop which will set `menu` to `False`. Otherwise -- it is an infinite loop so of course it just keep repeating the menu.

Something like:

```
while menu:
    print ("1. Set the Generation 0 values")
    print ("2. Display the Generation 0 values")
    print ("3. Run the model")
    print ("4. Export data")
    print ("5. Exit")
    choice = input("Please select your choice (1-5)")

    if choice == '1':
        pass #replace by code for choice 1
    elif choice == '2':
        pass #replace by code for choice 2
    elif choice == '3':
        pass #replace by code for choice 3
    elif choice == '4':
        pass #replace by code for choice 4
    else:
        menu = False #anything other than 1-4 breaks out of loop
```

In the comments I said things like "replace by code for choice 3". If the code in question is more than 1 or 2 lines, it should be abstracted to a function, so that the in the above code you could just have simple function calls for the various cases.